# Empty content in Qt Assistant

Tags: qt

I installed `Qt 5.12.0` on `macOS Catalina 10.15.6`, but my Qt Assistant is empty. I googled and it turns out I may need to download the `.qch` manually. Since I searched `.qch` in finder, no results. However, I couldn't find the corresponding source according to the keyword `qt assistant qch5.12.0 download`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Qt online installer to install Qt? If yes, you should find .qch files in `$QTDIR/Docs/Qt-5.12.0` (where QTDIR is the directory Qt is installed to, so e.g. `~/Qt`.

Comment: I use this link to download `qt-opensource-mac-x64-5.12.0.dmg` https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.12/5.12.0/
The folder Qt5.12.0 doesn't contain `Docs`

```
(base) ➜  Qt5.12.0 ls
InstallationLog.txt MaintenanceTool.dat components.xml
Licenses            MaintenanceTool.ini dist
MaintenanceTool.app Qt Creator.app      network.xml
```